# What "paring knife" best sharpens a fruit Y peeler?

Tags: sharpening

At [0:22](https://youtu.be/GL0gN5IgK8s?t=22) of this Oct. 5 2009 video, Douglas Jones (sous-chef of LA's Lucques) proclaimed that he "just bought a three-dollar paring knife". But his hand covers it, and I can't see what his paring knife looks like.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this article](https://www.russums-shop.co.uk/news/knives/q/date/2019/01/25/paring-knife-guide), there are 4 types of paring knife, the "spear tip", the "bird's beak", the "sheep's foot", and a "Western-style Japanese" paring knife.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

From your image, it looks like the chef is using a "sheep's foot" paring knife. However, for the purpose of sharpening a vegetable peeler, you only need a small straight length of the knife's blade, so specifically which type you use won't make too much difference except for the "bird's beak" as it is curved.